# can't access umbraco.uicontrols

Tags: umbraco

I created an .aspx page for custom section which want some umbraco controls to display.

For this i added the following line in .aspx page.

<%@ Register TagPrefix="umb" Namespace="umbraco.uicontrols" Assembly="controls" %>

But i didn't get the controls like UmbracoPanel and Pane..

Can you help me on this.

Answer (score 2):

Did you add *controls.dll* as a reference to your website project?

Comment: It got it worked after adding a reference to ClientDependency.Core.dll.